# Ignore phone's locale and always use English as locale

Tags: android

Is there a way to force using english as the locale for my android app even if the phone's locale is something other that english? The reason I want to do this is that I don't want my UI to change orientatoin from ltr to rtl.

Comment: "The reason I want to do this is that I don't want my UI to change orientatoin from ltr to rtl" -- then [use `android:supportsRtl="false"`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#supportsrtl).

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you that helped alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line

```
mStrLocale = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```

will return your current language, lets say `EN-US`

and with this you can hardcode your locale

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
      getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

and we use `Configuration` because of this

> This class describes all device configuration information that can
>   impact the resources the application retrieves. This includes both
>   user-specified configuration options (locale list and scaling) as well
>   as device configurations (such as input modes, screen size and screen
>   orientation).

is stated at this doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html

Comment: Do I have to do this for every activity or can I do it once when the application starts?

Comment: you can do it once  , and use it wherever you want